# What is host/computer SID in Windows AD? and what is needed to identify the elements of network with it?

Tags: security, windows-xp, active-directory, windows, sid

SID as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier

1) Help me to clarify the concept of computer SID on hypothetical situation:

suppose, I want to secure a network cable (for ex., from a workstation to the nearest switcher).

What should I minimally add to this cable in order to enable it security identifiable with SID:

- RAM?
- HDD (hard disk)?
- CPU?
- Operating system?

2) Having a Windows XP machine joined to AD domain,
will a parallel (multiboot) installation of a second Windows XP bring to machine the same host/computer SID or a new one?

3) If I use an image copy of hard disk (or hard disk) with Windows XP Pro from computer A to boot from computer B, with which computer SID - of PC A or of PC B - such booted Windows XP be identified by domain controller?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a SID is and how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand how the SID is generated in Windows. There are two parts to the SID. One part is domain dependent, the second part is a generated value and is unique to that workstation. The generation process does not include any hardware inputs, it is simply a random number. It is created during the install process, and stored in the registry. When it is domained, it gets a domain SID, which is the combination of the Domain's SID and the local machine's SID.

**1:** That is not how the SID works in windows. The SID belongs to the workstation only.

**2:** Assuming both XP installs were created through the normal install process, each parallel installation will have a unique SID. As far as AD is concerned, you have two machines on your workstation.

**3:** If PC B was created as an exact copy of PC A, the two will share a SID. There was a single install process where the SID was created and the registry populated. The Registry was copied as part of the imaging process. The Domain Controller will identify them as the same machine (mostly, but explaining would take a lot more text).

Users also have a SID, but that's not needed for this discussion.